# Image overflow in ListView Xamarin.Forms (Android)

Tags: android, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

have a ListView in which for each element of the List you have 3 buttons for 3 different options, when you enter the screen there are no overflow problems in the images of the ImageButton, but when you do the first scroll the sources start to overflow as shown in the following image

[image]

The images lose the center and are misaligned as you scroll up or down, this problem does not occur in iOS, only occurs in Android (version 6,7,8 and 9), apparently it is a problem like Android render the images

I tried, changing the ImageButton control to Button and the problem persists, also trying to assign the "Aspect" property to the ImageButton, but I'm not getting successful results, any help how to fix this? then my code XAML

```
   <ListView 
                ItemsSource="{Binding ListaRecintos}"
                SelectionMode="None"
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing, Mode=TwoWay}"        
                             RowHeight="80"
                             HasUnevenRows="True">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout
                                    Margin="0,4,0,0"
                                Orientation="Vertical">

                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3.9*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                                        <Label
                                            Text="{Binding Code}" 
                                            HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                            FontSize="Small" 
                                            WidthRequest="40"
                                            HeightRequest="30"
                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                            TextColor="{StaticResource das.color.texto}"
                                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                            Grid.Column="0">
                                        </Label>

                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                                                      Grid.Column="1">
                                             <Label                                 
                                            Text="{Binding Name}"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                            FontSize="Small" 
                                            HeightRequest="32"
                                            MaxLines="2"
                                            TextColor="{StaticResource das.color.texto}"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                                        </Label>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </Grid>

                                    <!--STACK BUTTON-->
                                    <StackLayout
                                              Orientation="Horizontal"
                                              HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                              Margin="0,1,1,0">

                                        <!--BUTTON 1-->
                                        <ImageButton 
                                            Source="ic_check_wt"
                                            Aspect="AspectFit"
                                            CornerRadius="0"
                                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource das.color.estado_success}"                                            
                                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                                            HeightRequest="35"
                                            WidthRequest="50"
                                            CommandParameter="2"
                                            Command="{Binding ControlAuditoriaCommand}"
                                            IsEnabled="{Binding EnabledButton}"/>

                                        <!--BUTTON 2-->
                                        <ImageButton 
                                            Source="ic_hammer"                                         
                                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource das.color.estado_primary}"                                        
                                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                                            CornerRadius="0"
                                            Aspect="AspectFit"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                                            HeightRequest="35"
                                            WidthRequest="50"
                                            CommandParameter="1"
                                            Command="{Binding ControlAuditoriaCommand}"
                                            IsEnabled="{Binding EnabledButton}"/>

                                        <!--BUTTON 3-->
                                        <ImageButton 
                                            Source="ic_arrow_up"
                                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource das.color.estado_success}"                                           
                                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                                            CornerRadius="0"
                                            Aspect="AspectFit"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                                            HeightRequest="35"
                                            WidthRequest="50"
                                            CommandParameter="3"
                                            Command="{Binding ControlAuditoriaCommand}"
                                            IsEnabled="{Binding EnabledButton}"/>

                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

How can I avoid this behavior? Any help for me?

Comment: What's your Forms version ? What's the expected image ? IF possible could you provide a basic project for us to test ?

Comment: My version of Xamarin.Forms is 4.3.0.947036 the image I expected is the image centered and not deformed and unfortunately I can not provide the project in question, since it is from the company where I work

any help for me? @ColeXia-MSFT

Comment: I suggest you use (Frame + image ) instead of ImageButton , and add tapgesture on it .

Comment: Your solution is correct! apply it in response to mark it as correct @ColeXia-MSFT

Comment: How could the button cover the entire area of ​​the Frame? when I put the frame + button I have too much space between the button and the frame, will I explain?  @ColeXia-MSFT

Comment: Set HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions to FillAndExpand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use (Frame + image ) instead of ImageButton , and add tapgesture on it .